# Defining vector between two points in pst-solides3d

Tags: 3d, pst-solides3d

I'm experimenting with `pst-solides3d` and I faced certain behavior. According to documentation (6.3.2 Definition with 2 points, page 59)

> We can also define a vector with 2 given points A and B of R^3
>
> We then use the arguments definition=vecteur3d and args=xA yA zA xB yB
>   zB where(xA, yA, zA) and (xB, yB, zB) are the appropriate coordinates
>   of the points A and B
>
> If the points A and B were already defined, we can easily use the
>   named variables: args=A B.

So basically `definition=vecteur3d` should create a vector between two points. However, this MWE:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\psset{viewpoint=10 18 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=10,fontsize=10,unit=1}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-4)(5,4)
    \psSolid[object=grille,base=-3 3 -3 3]%
    \psSolid[object=plan,definition=equation,args={[0 0 1 0]},fillcolor=red!10,opacity=0.5,base=-3 3 -3 3]
    \psSolid[object=vecteur,definition=vecteur3d,args=-1 -1 0 1 1 0, linecolor=red]
    % note the args=-1 -1 0 1 1 0 above
    \axesIIID(0,0,0)(3,3,3)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

It seems the arguments are subtracted from each other, generating the new vector. Note that using `object=line` with 6 arguments generated expected results.

Have I misunderstood the definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. The `args=-1 -1 0 1 1 0` are setup as a difference of the coordinates of the points B and A. This gives a direction vector with components `2 2 0`.

Now `\psSolid[optional arguments](x,y,z)` positions the object at `(x,y,z)`.

Now you didn't use the optional argument `(x,y,z)` which then is interpreted as `(0,0,0)` which is the case in your sketch.

Try it that way, as I setup the point A as position of the vector object:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\psset{viewpoint=10 18 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=10,fontsize=10,unit=1}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-4)(5,4)
    \psSolid[object=grille,base=-3 3 -3 3]%
    \psSolid[object=plan,definition=equation,args={[0 0 1 0]},fillcolor=red!10,opacity=0.5,base=-3 3 -3 3]
    \psSolid[object=vecteur,definition=vecteur3d,args=-1 -1 0 1 1 0, linecolor=red](-1,-1,0)
    % note the args=-1 -1 0 1 1 0 above
    \axesIIID(0,0,0)(3,3,3)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Hope this will clear up some things.

**Addendum:** The object `line` defines a line (or a series of line segments). We use the option `args` to specify the points:

```
[object=line,args=A0 A1 ...An]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This solves the problem puzzling particularly because there is a special definition for vector subtract.